# How to extract google news with specific key word using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am new to scrapy, trying to extract google news from the the given link bellow:

```
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cholera+news&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik0KLV-JfYAhWLpY8KHVpaAL0Q_AUICigB&biw=1863&bih=966
```

"cholera" key word was provided that shows small blocks of various news associated with cholera key world further I try this with scrapy to extract the each block that contents individual news.

```
fetch("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cholera+news&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik0KLV-JfYAhWLpY8KHVpaAL0Q_AUICigB&biw=1863&bih=966")

 response.css(".ts._JGs._KHs._oGs._KGs._jHs::text").extract()
```

where `.ts._JGs._KHs._oGs._KGs._jHs::text` represent the `div class="ts _JGs _KHs _oGs _KGs _jHs` for each block of news.

but it return None.

Comment: you should be using `https://news.google.com/` as the url in my opinion, after that, go to the search box and fill the search form. by your query, in this case Cholera

Comment: Consider fetching the data through [RSS](https://news.google.com/news/rss/search/section/q/cholera/cholera)

Answer (score 0):

In `scrapy shell` uses `view(response)` and you will see in web browser what you `fetch()`.

Google uses JavaScript to display data, but it can also send page which doesn't use JavaScript. But page without JavaScript usually has different tags and classes.

You can also turn off JavaScript in your browse and then open Google to see tags.

Try this:

```
response.css('#search td ::text').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling I find out a way to scrap desired data with very simple trick,

```
fetch("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cholera+news&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik0KLV-JfYAhWLpY8KHVpaAL0Q_AUICigB&biw=1863&bih=966")
```

and css selector "class="g" tag can be used to extract desired block like this

```
 response.css(".g").extract()
```

which return list of  all the individual news blocks which can be further used on the basis of list index like this:

```
 response.css(".g").extract()[0]
```

or

```
 response.css(".g").extract()[1]
```